# Object tracking when lost and found again

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tracking, feature-extraction

I am new to opencv. My objective is to perform object tracking and track a specific object. Save the features for example and re-track it if it's lost and found again in the plane. How can i perform that tracking ? And then how can i search for features ?

Answer (score 0):

To resume track you need to learn appearance variation of tracked object. For such tasks usually used features extractor and classifier for each object track, during tracking, classifier learn tracked object appearance, to recognize it after track lost and resumed.
Here you can find some trackers: https://github.com/gnebehay/VOTR

Comment: What if i just use histogram based tracking or SURF for example ? Is it not going to work ?

Comment: Can't say anything, I know nothing about "specific object".

Comment: I am asking generelly. Lets say any object i wish. The logic is to keep its features and refresh them and search to find them again right? How can this be achieved ?

Comment: In general, you need some good general features set, train good general classifier during tracking lasts, put it to database, after track lost you do search in you database of general objects using general features, and if general distance metric in your feature space is minimal and not larger than some threshold you set, you can reassign this object to the track and update pattern stored in DB for this track.